# How can I run two queries and return two objects in my route call?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I would like to add another query call (using Mongoose for MongoDB) and return the object the same way I am returning my Car object. Is there a way I can run the second query for the router to return both objects?

```
router.get('/:car', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) =>
    Car.find({user: req.user._id, car: req.params.car}).lean().exec( function(err, cars){    
        return res.render('cardetails', {
            user: req.user,
            cars: JSON.stringify(cars),
            carnum: req.params.car,
            content: cars[0].content,
            status: cars[0].status
        });
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.postDelete=(req,res,next)=>{
  const shname=req.body.sname;
  let fod='';
  Shop.find().then(food=>{
    fod=food;
    return fod;
  }).then(result=>{    //1st obj
    Shop.findOne({shopName:shname})
    .populate({path: 'foodId',
    match: { isVerified: true }})
    .then(foods=>{  //2nd obj
      console.log(foods);
      res.render('admin/delete',{
        pageTitle:'Delete Food',
        path:'admin/deletefood',
        foodlist:result,   
        flist:foods.foodId
    });
    })

    .catch(err=>{
      console.log(err);
      res.send("error");
    });

  })

  .catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
    res.send("error");
  });

};

refer the above snippet
```